# If an existing SSRS report is giving wrong data and I have troubleshoot it...where do I start first?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, report, reportbuilder

I have few existing SSRS reports here which are giving some inaccurate info. I want to fix those...where should I start? is it the data source in Report Builder? Where else should I look?

Thanks

Comment: In order for someone to help, you will need to provide more information. What is inaccurate? Can you post a screenshot of the inaccuracies you are seeing?

Comment: Could be a number of issues here... Data Source (what server are you pointing to), Data Set (Stored Procedure or embedded query in SSRS), Data Set Groupings, Any filters on the Data Sets. Just to name a few places to start.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find the query that is being run or the stored procedure in the datasets. Then you can open those and see what datasource it is using. Some could be shared so you might have to look a bit to find them but that tells you the server. So then you can troubleshoot.